# Problem removing Windows Firewall Rule when several matching names exist

Tags: c#, firewall, windows-firewall

I have this code to remove rules from Windows Firewall:

```
        public static int WinFirewall_RuleRemove(string strName, string strLocalPorts, string strRemotePorts) {

            int intFailed = 0;

            try {

                // Create an instance of the Windows Firewall Manager
                INetFwPolicy2 firewallPolicy = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2"));

                // Filter rules based on all criteria (Name, LocalPorts, and RemotePorts)
                var matchingRules = firewallPolicy.Rules
                    .OfType<INetFwRule>()
                    .Where(x => x.Name == strName && x.LocalPorts == strLocalPorts && x.RemotePorts == strRemotePorts)
                    .ToList();

                // Check if any matching rule was found
                if (matchingRules.Count > 0) {

                    foreach (var rule in matchingRules) {
                        firewallPolicy.Rules.Remove(rule.Name);
                    }

                } else {
                    intFailed = 1;
                }

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                intFailed = 1;
                Debug.WriteLine($"WinFirewall_RuleRemove(): {ex}");
            }

            return intFailed;
        }
```

When several ***names*** in the fw list match, it's deleting the first it finds, even though I specify local and remote ports as well during the filtering. The filtering *does* match the correct rules.

Example:

I have this list of rules before removing (note the "PPGooey" names):

[image]

Now, after I remove the ones matching port `9030`, it removes the ones at the *top* of the list anyway, which in this case is port `53`:

[image]

All I can really find on the `.remove()` method shows the only argument it asks for is the "name"; so I can't also specify anything else, like the ports...

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe do it via `Powershell.Create` and `Remove-NetFirewallRule` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/remove-netfirewallrule?view=windowsserver2022-ps

Comment: @Charlieface That is another method I plan to try down the road a bit, but before that I'd really like to try doing it w/out passing everything to a command-line.

Comment: You don't need to go out to a command liine, you can run Powershell directly from C# using `Powershell.Create` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/adding-and-invoking-commands?view=powershell-7.3